# Unable to get NodeJS Routes when executing lambda functions locally getting Page not found response

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-offline

I am currently working on a Node.JS application deployed as an AWS Lambda function. When I try to access the routes locally it responds with page not found.
I have different config files for different functions listed. Some are public routes and some are protected routes. This problem is happening only for protected routes.

my config file: course.yml

```
    handler: src/course/aicc/handler.do
    events:
      - http:
          path: /aicc/{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:
              - Accept
              - Origin
              - DNT
              - User-Agent
              - Referer
              - X-experience-api-version
              - x-amz-date
              - x-requested-with
              - X-Requested-With
              - Content-Type # Part of the Default List
              - X-Amz-Date # Part of the Default List
              - Authorization # Part of the Default List
              - X-Api-Key # Part of the Default List
              - X-Amz-Security-Token # Part of the Default List
              - X-Amz-User-Agent # Part of the Default List
            allowCredentials: false
      - http:
          path: /aicc/
          method: ANY
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:
              - Accept
              - Origin
              - DNT
              - User-Agent
              - Referer
              - X-experience-api-version
              - x-amz-date
              - x-requested-with
              - X-Requested-With
              - Content-Type # Part of the Default List
              - X-Amz-Date # Part of the Default List
              - Authorization # Part of the Default List
              - X-Api-Key # Part of the Default List
              - X-Amz-Security-Token # Part of the Default List
              - X-Amz-User-Agent # Part of the Default List
            allowCredentials: false
      - schedule: rate(15 minutes) # here to avoid cold starts of the Lambda
```

serverless.yml file which reads from the above config file:

```
 - serverless-plugin-include-dependencies
 - serverless-plugin-log-subscription
 - serverless-offline

custom:
  awsId: 8066631*****
  logSubscription:
    enabled: ${file(conf/vpc-${self:provider.stage}.js):es_lambda_enabled}
    destinationArn: ${file(conf/vpc-${self:provider.stage}.js):es_lambda_function}

package:
  excludeDevDependencies: true
  exclude:
    - conf/**
    - lib/**
    - spec/**
    - .eslintrc.json
    - .jsbeautifyrc
    - package.json
    - package-lock.json
    - rebuildLocalModules.sh
    - ToDoItems.md
  include:
    - ./project_modules/**

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 10
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  group: ${opt:group, 'course'}
  region: us-east-2
  logRetentionInDays: 3
  deploymentBucket:
    name: serverless-safetyserve-${self:provider.region}

  environment:
    STAGE: "${self:provider.stage}"
    REGION: us-east-2
    SSM_KEYS: "[\"/${self:provider.stage}/api\"]"
    JWT_SECRET : ${ssm:/${self:provider.stage}/jwt/secret~true}

  vpc:
    securityGroupIds: ${file(conf/vpc-${self:provider.stage}.js):security}
    subnetIds: ${file(conf/vpc-${self:provider.stage}.js):subnets}

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - lambda:InvokeFunction
      Resource:
        - "*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "ssm:GetParameter"
        - "ssm:GetParameters"
      Resource:
        - "arn:aws:ssm:${self:provider.region}:${self:custom.awsId}:parameter/${self:provider.stage}/*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "ses:SendEmail"
        - "ses:SendRawEmail"
      Resource:
        - "*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:GetObject"
        - "s3:PutObject"
        - "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        - "s3:DeleteObject"
      Resource: 
        - "arn:aws:s3:::download.roadready.org/*"
        - "arn:aws:s3:::safetyserve-cloudfront-logs/*"
        - "arn:aws:s3:::static-sites-safetyserve/${self:provider.stage}/*"
        - "arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.stage}.roadready.org/*"
        - "arn:aws:s3:::config-safetyserve/${self:provider.stage}/*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:GetObject"
        - "s3:PutObject"
      Resource: 
        - "arn:aws:s3:::reports-safetyserve/${self:provider.stage}/*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:ListBucket"
      Resource: 
        - "arn:aws:s3:::static-sites-safetyserve"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
      Resource:
        - "*"

service: ${file(conf/sls-${self:provider.group}.yml):service}
functions: ${file(conf/sls-${self:provider.group}.yml):functions}
resources: ${file(conf/sls-${self:provider.group}.yml):resources}
```

Although this is not a protected route still I face this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.